gsap pinning elements in next js and locomotive scroll
I'm trying to implement a GSAP timeline with Locomotive Scroll beta  to pin an element while scrolling in a Next.js component. The code works perfectly in a normal HTML and JS environment, but it's not functioning as expected in Next.js.
NOTE: I'm using locomotive scroll beta.
Here is the minimal demo with normal html environment:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gsap-timeline-forked-3dqjgv?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A8%2C18
Here is the Next Js version:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/c4cq6q?file=%2Fpin-element%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2FPinComponent.js%3A28%2C11
I'm new to GSAP and I'm looking for assistance to fix the issue.
I want to make it work just as the normal html environment.

i dont know why you changed gsap options in react like this,
 scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: pinPosition.current,
    start: "top top",
    end: `bottom top+=${bottom}`,
    pin: elToPin.current,
    scrub: true,
    markers: true,
  },

but this will give you the same result.
 scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: pinPosition.current,
    start: "top top",
    end: `bottom top`,
    pin: elToPin.current,
    scrub: true,
    markers: true,
  },

sandbox
